# Creating extra rows in TextArea when input has reached the end of the field?

Tags: jquery, html, textbox, autoresize

When typing in a new facebook comments box the height of the textbox changes according to how many lines the box has. What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://github.com/jaz303/jquery-grab-bag/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks man. If you put that in an answer I'd accept it :P.

Comment: I'll gladly accept that offer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try elastic http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/

Comment: I ended up using your solution due to its simplicity. Thanks ^_^.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help: https://github.com/jaz303/jquery-grab-bag/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js

Answer (score 0):

The hight of comment box is standard one. You can only define the width of the comment box.
Height will be automatically adjusted.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="example.com" num_posts="2" width="600"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: I'm not using the facebook api i'm trying to replicate it.